# python site requests, print error on boolean class

Tags: python

I want to make a code that shows if the site is working or not, so far I tried this code but it is not working:

code:

```
import requests
requestt = requests.get("https://www.google.com")

status = (requestt)
print(status)
print(status == "<Response [200]>")
```

output:

```
<Response [200]>
False
```

why??
i have tried a lot of things but still not working.
i wanna make a code that show if the site is working or not.

Comment: you are comparing a <class 'requests.models.Response'> type with string. Check what requests.models.Response class contains and use print(type(status)) to make this clear

Comment: @Braian Dimitrius If you find my answer helpfull, please upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: @needtobe, sorry but i don't have 15 reputation

Comment: The title says "print error on boolean class"; what error is that? I suspect the error message gives a hint to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response status of `Response` object in `requests` library is stored in `status_code` attribute.
Regarding that, please use:

```
import requests
requestt = requests.get("https://www.google.com")

status = requestt.status_code
print(status)
print(status == 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you print is just a short representation of the result of the request.

If you want to test the status, you can use:

```
requestt.status_code == requests.codes.ok
```

It will be What you print is just a short representation of the result of the request.

If you want to test the status, you can use:

```
requestt.status_code == requests.codes.ok
```

It will be `True` if the status code is 200 (OK), `False` otherwise. In any case, `requestt.status_code` will be the status code as integer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that the `status` variable is an object of type `<class 'requests.models.Response'>`. You can see this by running the following:

```
import requests
requestt = requests.get("https://www.google.com")

status = (requestt)
print(type(status))
```

To actually retrieve the status, you need to access the `status_code` property of the request object:

```
import requests
requestt = requests.get('https://www.google.com')

status = requestt.status_code
print(type(status))  # will now return "<class 'int'>"

print(status == 200)  # will print "True"
```

The documentation for the `status_code` property is [in the documentation for the Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes).